# Selectively run tests in broken project using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104415/run-tests-in-broken-project-using-sbt) question on running sbt tests in a broken build, how can I enhance the **just-test** action below so that it has similar functionality to test-only.  I.e. **just-test-only *SomeTest**

```
import sbt._

class Project(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
  lazy val justTest = testTask(testFrameworks, testClasspath, testCompileConditional.analysis, testOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy should do the trick:

```
lazy val justTestOnly = testQuickMethod(testCompileConditional.analysis, testOptions)(
  o => testTask(testFrameworks, testClasspath, testCompileConditional.analysis, o)
)
```

It does the same thing that `testOnly` does - forwards the task creation to a helper called `testQuickMethod`. The only difference is in the function it gives it in the 2nd parameter list - it uses test options `o` to create a `Task` using the `testTask` method, but without appending the `dependsOn` at the end.

Appending `dependsOn` to `testTask` could be used to create some dependencies for this task.

Comment: Perfect.  I was getting lost in the documentation http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/CustomActions

Comment: Yeah, well - often the best way to find info is to just grep the source - this is how I find about the things above. :)